# Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, not low on memory

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

I'm running a computationally intensive task that reads data from the viewfinder using UIGetScreenImage and does computations on it, repeatedly. After about 60 seconds (on 3GS) I'm getting a crash every time. But I can't debug it, because I get this:

```
Program received signal:  “0”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")
(gdb) continue
The program is not being run.
```

And at this point I'm toast, the stack trace is all blank.

I've used Instruments, object allocations, allocations, activity monitor, and they all show that I'm not leaking. In activity monitor for example physical memory used rises from 77MB to to 112 MB and stays there (up and down a bit) until the crash.

Anyone have an idea of what to try?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? 3.2.3 apparently has some issues.

Comment: Yes I'm on 3.2.3 ... so with a different version I might be able to connect the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You might have some recursion that's got a bit out of control?

I've seen your symptoms happen when I've accidentally call a setter from within a setter i.e.

```
-(void)setX:(int)value {
    self.x = value; //!< Oops, accidentally called this method again :(
}
```

and you get odd errors from the debugger because you've broken the stack. Don't know how this answer helps you find the error though :(

Are you using any version control at all - I'd fix this by stepping back though your changes and finding the change that causes the bug?

Comment: heh, that's a nasty bug. But no, it doesn't look anything like that. Also, one odd thing is that the stack trace does have a number of line (14 I think) but they are all completely blank and if I click on them nothing happens.

Comment: As for VC, it's all in git but older versions were so leaky that they crashed even sooner ... I'm not sure if that kind of strategy would be any use in this case.

Comment: Looks like you have no choice - NSLog all over the place and a few late nights :( Unlucky!